# Raster export for regressions analysis

Tags: qgis, arcgis-9.3, spatial-statistics, statistics

I have the following issue: 
I am trying to do a regression analysis between the (z) values of two rasters. What I would ideally like to have is the raster output not as grid but rather a list of x1y1z1 x2y2z2, x3y3z3,... 
Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: ArcGIS 9.3. 
Also run QGIS on my laptop

Comment: this type of output is easy to do from autocad map. I will look for a method in arcmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export tif again (may be in ArcGIS))and find *.dbf file. This has all the values you need.

Comment: Hi! 
I exported as point...but needed to use raster calculator (multiply by 10000) for each raster to avoid trunking off decimals. 
Else - works! 

Cheers!